# Sinch app to app voice calling not working

Tags: android, sinch

**Using Sinch in android kotlin I'm trying app to app calling. I'm receiving incoming call but  call.answer() is not working.App still ringing when i accept call.What to do?**

*I'm using latest sinch version 3.17.4
locat details

```
Request 5a607103-ea68-4a55-bae1-0377a7c40fb2|2 completed with exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "rebtelsdk.pubnub.com": No address associated with hostname

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzDhs.png
```

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately I can not tell what is going wrong in your implementation, I recommend that you first use our Push Sample apps (included on the SDK Samples folder).
That is in Java, not in Kotlin, but you should be fine.
The samples work fine, and they should give you a clear perception of what need to be changed on your code.

Sinch Voice & Video Team